# IIS: wwwroot directories of an IIS with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

How can I get all (physical) wwwroot directories (home directories) of an IIS with C# from the IIS metabase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you're using IIS6:**

You need to add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices` in Visual Studio in the Add References .NET assemblies tab:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace ListRootAppPathsIIS6
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://Localhost/W3SVC"))
      {
        foreach (DirectoryEntry w3svc in de.Children)
        {
          if (w3svc.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer")
          {
            string rootPath = 
                String.Format("IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/{0}/root", w3svc.Name);
            using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(rootPath))
            {
              string info = String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", 
                  w3svc.Name, 
                  w3svc.Properties["ServerComment"].Value, 
                  root.Properties["Path"].Value);

              Console.WriteLine(info);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

**If you're using IIS7:**

Add a reference to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll`

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

namespace ListRootAppPathsIIS7
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
      {
        foreach (var site in serverManager.Sites)
        {
          var app = site.Applications.Where(a => a.Path == "/").First();
          var vdir = app.VirtualDirectories.Where(v => v.Path == "/").First();
          string info = String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", 
              site.Id, 
              site.Name, 
              Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(vdir.PhysicalPath));

          Console.WriteLine(info);
        }
      }
      Console.ReadLine();

    }
  }
}
```

The first method (using `System.Directoryservices`) will work with IIS7 provided you've installed the IIS6 management compatibilities bits.

In both cases you need to be running as an Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You could call out to

```
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list vdir
```

(using the API to get the right folder of course). And filter for "*site*\" (for the default site "Default Web Site/". I assume there is some API to do this (but, certainly for older IIS versions, this was very script orientated, so would require dealing with `IDispatch` to invoke methods and property-gets).

This does require an elevated process on IIS7 and 7.5 (unless sufficient rights to IIS have been delegated).